# How to display data from 2 tables that already have data on Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, phtml, quote

How to display data from two tables ***quote_item***

[image]
and ***sales_order_item***

[image]

from the database to **.phtml file**.

Can anyone help me step by step, I am new to Magento, if someone can help me, it's very useful for me, **help me, please!** Many thanks

Comment: This article should help you  - https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-join-2-tables-magento-2.html

Comment: what typ pf data you want can you add expected result in your question